# How to subtract values of two columns and add to a new column in text file using awk/bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I want to subtract the values from two columns and add result into a new column (at the very end) using awk or bash. the data is in a txt file.

I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} NR == 1 {$20 = "tr_pe"} NR >=2 {$20= $5-$11}1' <filename
```

or

```
awk OFS="\t" \{$(NF+1)=$5-$11}1' filename.txt
```

The first code did the subtraction but saved it in column 2 instead of at the end, and I realised that it actually did not get saved to the txt.file. Second one did some calculation but it was not accurate

What I want to do - subtract values from column 5 with column 11 and save it under header tr_pre (which falls into column 20 at the end of all the 19 columns in the file). Columns are separated by tab.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2):

You could use next after line 1 to continue the iteration. To print the result at the end, you can print the whole line using `$0` followed by the value that you want at the end.

```
cat filename.txt

c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

For example

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}
{$1=$1}
NR == 1 {
  print $0, "tr_pre"
  next
} 
{
  print $0, $5-$11
}' filename.txt > output.txt
```

output.txt

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 tr_pre
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  -6
```

Comment: thank you! i adapted the command and got it to save the tr_pe variable onto a new file instead of the old one. Worked for my purpose!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, this should solve your problem.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR == 1 {print $0, "tr_pre"} NR >=2 {print $0, $5 - $11}' filename.tsv > file_with_new_tr_pre_column.tsv
```

If there are other confounding factors, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print $0 "\t" (NR==1?"tr_pre":$5-$11)}' oldfile > newfile
```